# Generic package in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Is it possible to have a generic package? 
This means that when I instantiate the entity I provide some generic and the package will depend on that.

I have a block which I want to use several times, each time with different package (I.e. different parameters)

I have to use package because I want to use array of arrays and I could do that only with packages.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but that's a [VHDL-2008](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_major/#PackageGenerics) feature. So whether you will be able to use it depends on your tools.

This feature is really powerful.

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925361/passing-generics-to-record-port-types).

Answer (score 0):

This is currently possible with Xilinx's Vivado toolset, which supports many VHDL-2008 features. Ref other answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63291059/2658159).

Answer (score -3):

no, it is not, because library clauses are evaluated statically, what you would need is something like dynamic binding which is not possible in vhdl.

However, it seems that you want a convenient way of providing different "sets" of generic values. In that case I suggest you look at user defined types of records or arrays. You can define, e.g., an array of records containing your configuration data and provide each instantiation with its own set out of the array. Neat and clean, and afaik all tools support that.

Comment: Oh, I see.. I thought you would want to include different packages based on the value of some generic