# Generic Records (attempted via vhdl 2008 generic package)

Tags: vhdl

I want to write a library for component `C`, the component is split internally into two supcomponents `c1` and `c2`, which are configurable by generics. The submodules should be connected by a record, that depends on the generics. The record should also be used within the components. Usually I would instantiate the record in a `package`, and use the package in the files for the subcomponents and in the file for the component. Since it is generic I figured using a generic Package (VHDL-2008) might offer a solution.

The Problem is I need to access the record also from within the subcomponents. To do so I need to `use thePackage`, however to use a generic package I need to pass initial values (as far as I know).

So I tried (note: Iam not working with records here, I am just trying to get access to a generic package from a generic component, where I parameterize(?) the package with the parameters of the component):

```
entity genericPackagePart is
    generic(
        outputValue : integer
    );
    port(
        result: out integer
    );
end entity;

architecture behav of genericPackagePart is
    package test is new work.genericPackage
    generic map(
        genSize => outputValue
    );

    use work.test.all;
begin
    result <= dummy;  -- dummy is a constant from genericPackage set to the value genSize (generic parameter)
end architecture;
```

However I get the following errors from modelsim:

```
** Error: (vcom-11) Could not find work.test.
** Error: genericPackagePart.vhd(17): (vcom-1195) Cannot find expanded name "work.test".
** Error: genericPackagePart.vhd(17): Unknown expanded name.
** Error: genericPackagePart.vhd(19): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "dummy".
** Error: genericPackagePart.vhd(20): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

**Update:**
I tried wrapping the `genericPackagePart` in a generic package and to instantiate the  `genericPackage` from within that package with the generics, this did not work either.

The flow would have been:

- Testbench => Instantiate `genericPackagePart` and `genericPackage` with generic parameters
- The record is available in the testbench from `genericPackage`
- Inside `genericPackagePart` `genericPackage` is instantiated with the parameters passed to `genericPackagePart`
- the record is available inside `genericPackagePart`

Modelsim gave Errors (`test` is the name I gave to the parameterizes instance of `genericPackage` in `genericPackagePart`, this is from the compile of `genericPackagePart`):

```
** Error: (vcom-11) Could not find work.test.
** Error: genericPackagePart.vhd(11): (vcom-1195) Cannot find expanded name "work.test".
** Error: genericPackagePart.vhd(11): Unknown expanded name.
** Error: genericPackagePart.vhd(13): near "entity": expecting END
```

---

I looked at [Passing Generics to Record Port Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925361/passing-generics-to-record-port-types) but that does not solve the issue of the package instantiation based on generics

---

For completness here is the package and a testbench:

**Package:**

```
package genericPackage is
    generic(genSize : integer := 1);

    constant dummy : integer := genSize;
end package;
```

**Testbench:**

```
package myGenericPackage is new work.genericPackage
generic map(
    genSize => 5
);

use work.myGenericPackage.all;

entity genericPackageTestbench is
end entity;

architecture testbench of genericPackageTestbench is
    signal testsignal : integer;
    signal testsignal2 : integer;
    signal dummy : integer := 12;

    component genericPackagePart is
    generic(
        outputValue : integer
    );
    port(
        result: out integer
    );
    end component;
begin
    test : process is
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        testsignal <= dummy;
        wait for 20 ns;
        testsignal <= work.myGenericPackage.dummy;
        wait;
    end process;

    testPart: genericPackagePart
        port map(result => testsignal2)
        generic map(outputValue => 128);
end architecture;
```

Comment: Daft question... do you have VHDL 2008 turned on in the compiler settings?

Comment: yes (`vcom -2008 ...` using only modelsim currently), also some smaller parts worked (testbench without `testPart`). The Problem is with the package instantiation inside the architecture (first code snippet). unfortunately I have no VHDL book for vhdl 2008 to check, any recommendations are welcome. The issue is that I thought instantiating the package with the generic parameters would be the way to go, ot get a record, that is generic and only defined once.

Comment: @MartinThompson: I am glad the SO VHDL Guru turned up to take a look :p

Comment: gulp - no pressure there then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem was that your package `test` needs to be defined in the entity area, not the architecture area:

```
package genericPackage is
    generic(genSize : integer := 1);
    constant dummy : integer := genSize;
end package;
entity genericPackagePart is
    generic(outputValue : integer);
    port(result : out integer);

    -- *** Generic package instantiated here ***
    package test is new work.genericPackage
       generic map(genSize => outputValue);

end entity;
architecture behav of genericPackagePart is
    use test.all;
begin
    result <= dummy;  -- dummy is from genericPackage (=genSize)
end architecture;
```

Here's how I tested it (based on your testbench):

```
package myGenericPackage is new work.genericPackage
   generic map(genSize => 5);

use work.myGenericPackage.all;

entity genericPackageTestbench is
end entity;

architecture testbench of genericPackageTestbench is
    signal testsignal  : integer;
    signal testsignal2 : integer;
begin
    test : process is
    begin
        testsignal <= work.myGenericPackage.dummy;
        wait for 20 ns;

        assert testsignal = work.myGenericPackage.dummy 
            report "test signal should be work.myGenericPackage.dummy" 
            severity error;
        assert testsignal2 = 128 report "testsignal2 /= 128" severity error;
        report "testsignal = " & integer'image(testsignal);
        report "testsignal2 = " & integer'image(testsignal2);
        report "Finished";
        wait;
    end process;

    testPart : entity work.genericPackagePart
        generic map(outputValue => 128)
        port map(result         => testsignal2);
end architecture;
```

Compiled and simulated with Modelsim 10.2:

```
vcom -2008 genpacktest.vhd; vsim -c genericPackageTestbench -do "run -all; quit"
```

Which reports:

```
# Loading std.standard
# Loading work.genericpackage
# Loading work.mygenericpackage
# Loading work.genericpackagetestbench(testbench)
# Loading work.genericpackagepart(behav)
# run -all 
# ** Note: Finished
#    Time: 20 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /genericpackagetestbench
# ** Note: testsignal = 5
#    Time: 20 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /genericpackagetestbench
# ** Note: testsignal2 = 128
#    Time: 20 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /genericpackagetestbench
#  quit
```

Comment: sorry for replying so late, but i wanted to try it out before I accept. It works splendid (also with modelsim 10.1d) now I will use this for generic records. thanks a bunch. You do not, by chance, know any good literature/reference for vhdl 2008, that shows for instance where I may instantiate packages or the like?

Comment: "VHDL-2008: Just the New Stuff" is the only VHDL2008 book I have - if you're already familiar with VHDL-pre-2008 it's a great way to figure out  (as the title implies) the new stuff.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look before I consider buying it, I actually hoped for something like a crisp reference with also the old stuff (e.g. a short grammar that tells me where I am allowed to instantiate packages, but I guess I will have to combine the vhdl 93 literature with this book), so far I tried googling and the synplify help

Comment: I'd hoped Doulos had updated their golden reference guide to 2008, but it appears not.  Still worth consideration as a great short-form of the whole language pre 2008... http://www.doulos.com/content/products/golden_reference_guides.php#Anchor-Th-61209

Comment: Well they have a short [overview](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/), however it just gives one a rough idea were to get started. (Even though it helped me to figure out what type I need to 'cast' to (if that is the proper vhdl term), to use the reduction operators.)

Comment: Actually I have osrt of a follow up question: If I have a record inside my generic package and want to use that as an input for the entity, how would I go about doing that? (I tried moving the package instantiation between the generic and the port map but this gave `Error: genericPackagePart.vhd(9): near "port": syntax error`) is this possible or do I have to go through some hoops and wrap my component in a generic package and load the package with the record in the entities package to allow an entity declaration with the erecord from the generic package?

Comment: (I feel that this is not worth a new so question, but the comment box does not seem to be the right place either though)

Comment: @ted:I'd raise it as a new question - and maybe link back to this one within it for context