# Emacs auto indenting does not support the VHDL 2008 generic packages instantiation?

Tags: emacs, package, vhdl

When trying to instantiate the generic package as instructed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056291/generic-records-attempted-via-vhdl-2008-generic-package)

it does compile but when trying to auto indent the file with emacs, it becomes messy. Does the emacs have any updates regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is better you ask the authors and maintainers of the emacs VHDL mode directly. Their website is here: http://www.iis.ee.ethz.ch/~zimmi/emacs/vhdl-mode.html

You can then answer your own question here.