# How to create a record with an array field without defining a type for the array in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I can write:

```
type bit2_t is array (0 to 1) of bit;
type record0 is record
    bit2 : bit2_t;
end record;
```

But I'd like to do it without defining `bit2_t` since I don't need it, something like:

```
type record0 is record
    bit2 : array (0 to 1) of bit;
end record;
```

But if I try that, GHDL 0.34 says:

```
type mark expected in a subtype indication
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply declaring the array instance incorrectly. Instead of

```
type bit2_t is array (0 to 1) of bit;
type record0 is record
  bit2 : array (0 to 1) of bit;
end record;
```

You need to use

```
type bit2_t is array (integer range <>) of bit;
type record0 is record
  bit2 : bit2_t(0 to 1);
end record;
```

If you wanted an array of 2-bit arrays of bits, you would use

```
type bit2_t is array (0 to 1) of bit;
type bit2_array_t is array (integer range <>) of bit2_t;
type record0 is record
  bit2 : bit2_array_t(0 to 7);  -- '7' or whatever your range needs to be
end record;
```

You could make this slightly more generic by changing the `7` to a constant, something like `bit2 : bit2_array_t(0 to BIT2_ARRAY_LENGTH-1);`.

If you want to have a record type that is in some way paramatized, as far as I know you can only achieve this using package generics, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16078428/4090959). Your code would use the package as described, and this package would declare your record type with array sizes based on a `generic` parameter. By instantiating the package with a different value for the `generic` in each case, your `record` could have different element sizes for these different cases.

I would note that I do not believe package generics are widely supported by synthesis tools.

Comment: I don't quite understand, your second example still defines the `bit2_t` type, which is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 Hm, I don't understand what you're asking for in that case, sorry. It sounds like you want to define a record type without predefining the type of one of its elements? If so I'm not sure that is possible.

Comment: Yup that's it. Just to write less. Like we can do in C.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功  It's not possible.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 I updated my answer linking to another existing answer, maybe that helps? I didn't see much point in copying code from that answer into mine.